# Como criar um vetor a partir de outro, porém seus elementos devem ser maiores que x?

Tags: r

Gostaria que `v2` assumisse apenas os valores que fossem maiores que `x`. Ele até chega perto, porém cria um vetor com elementos lógicos. Gostaria que fossem os elementos de `v1`.

```
v1 <-c (1500, 1600, 1700, 1800)

x <- 1600

v2 <- v1 > x
```

Comment: `v1[v1 > x]` ou `subset(x = v1, v1 > x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sem apelar para uma função pronta, você pode simplesmente utilizar um condicional dentro de um for loop como no exemplo abaixo:

```
v1=c(1500,1600,1700,1800)
v2=c()
for (i in v1) {
  if (i>1600) {
   v2=c(v2,i)
  }
}
print(v2)
```

É ineficiente e leva muita sintaxe, mas você entende melhor o que o computador está fazendo. Soluções pré-prontas incluem o uso de funções. Um exemplo é a função `Filter`:

```
v1=c(1500,1600,1700,1800)

v2=Filter(function(x) x>1600, v1)

print(v2)
```

Ou, em uma solução ainda mais simples sugerida no comentário por outro usuário:

```
v2=v1[v1 > x]
print(v2)
```

Comment: No `Filter` é `v1` e naõ `v`.

Comment: obrigado @RuiBarradas . Corrigido